# AJAX functionality in WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am looking for approach and not any code here - What is the best method to implement ajax like content fetch (from DB) in WinForms ?

Comment: Use Async-Await, Background worker, etc to accomplish asynchronous operations in WinForms. Call it asynchronous task, not Ajax.

Comment: I was referring to something similar to AJAX when I mentioned AJAX like functionality not AJAX itself. I was able to get my task done using timers.

Comment: Using timer is definitely not the best way to implement something like ajax. Timer is useful if some task should occur periodically. But again it is not like Ajax, it is scheduling.

Comment: I am looking for a data fetch for some of the controls in my form periodically. What do you suggest

Comment: Since it should occur periodically, using Timer is OK. If you want your UI to be responsive while fetching the data, you should use Async Await or Background Worker from the Timer Tick event.

Comment: Thanks, Its a read only dashboard sort of thing that stays alive for 8 hours a day and so there is no user interaction. Will try the Async-Await option next time around. Your response should be marked as answer and unfortunately I do not have the access level to do it.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is a web term. Retrieve your data via an API.